# Powershell script to filter Windows Event Logs

Tags: powershell, event-log

I am trying to write a script to filter the Window's Event logs. I want to only pull up events that have a specific phrase in the Exception Message line.

I have tried several iterations of this script, I was trying to query the text behind "Exception Message:" so that I can filter for the phrase, "Unable to establish a connection to the database"

This is what my failing script looks like:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application |
    Select-Object -Expand Message |
    Select-String -Pattern '(?<=Exception message:\s+)\d+' |
    Select-Object -Expand Matches |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty value |
    where -filterscript {$_.Message -contains 'Unable to establish a connection to the database'}
```

This is what the Event log massage looks like that I want to filter on:

**Exception information:**

**Exception type: Exception**

**Exception message: Unable to establish a connection to the database. It may be down.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need in any additional filtering. `Get-EventLog` can do this by itself:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Message "*Unable to establish a connection to the database*"
```